# Strategy for Docker image deployment in ports in server for production

Tags: docker, deployment

I developed some microservice by using Spring Boot. Now I am trying to deploy in server by using Docker. I already installed Docker in my remote server. And also test deployment is also successfully done by using Docker Compose.

When I am testing deployment in server, one image deployed in 8080 port in server and another was deployed in 8085. I have some confusions in deployment in ports, since I only started exploration in Dockers and containers world.

Here are my questions:

1. Currently I only tested with 2 ports in server ie 8080 and 8085. In my project I have 20 microservices. So do I need to choose these ports manually in random manner?
2. When I creating Docker containers all containers are creating in 8080 port, Later I deployed that in another port in server. Is this best practice for creating container images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every MS must have it's own port. you can choose the ports.
2. No, Couchbase Web Administration Port for example has internal port 8091, you can use as you said another port in server but not all containers are creating in 8080 port, you should choose the port. In case of couchbase you set -p 10000:8091.I choose the port 10000 randomly. (-p for publish)